# How do I re-install Visual Studio.net's trial edition?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm working on getting the full license for VS 2008 (or my boss is) but my trial has expired, and I need to do some work.

How can I re-install?

Or, if I install on a different machine (or virtual machine) - how can I get another key without going through the whole download process from MS again?

Answer (score 7):

I'd think you could probably do most of the same work in the free [Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/Express/), until you get the full license.